# mvc server-side validation for jquery ajax post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation

How this can be done ?

For example in my model i have

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[RegularExpression(@"[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}", ErrorMessage = "Incorrect email")]
public string EmailTo { get; set; }
```

My current test new controller is

```
[HttpPost]
public EmptyResult SendAgreementEmail(AgreementReportModel model)
{
   bool t = ModelState.IsValid;
   return new EmptyResult();
}
```

ModelState.IsValid is valid even if emailto is null.

And js function

```
 function SendEmailWithJquery(offerID, agreementOfferID, customerID) {

    var emailTo = document.getElementById('txtEmailTo').value;
    var emailSubject = document.getElementById('txtEmailSubject').value;
    var emailBody = document.getElementById('txtEmailBody').value;

    var sendData = {
        OfferID: offerID,
        AgreementOfferID: agreementOfferID,
        CustomerID: customerID,
        EmailTo: emailTo,
        EmailSubject: emailSubject,
        EmailBody: emailBody
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Agreement/SendAgreementEmail",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(sendData),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }
    });
};
```

Is it possible at all to validate server-side for controller with json object and strong-typed view ?

Comment: why would you want to do validation on the server side, validation of a `email id` what is required and i guess its possible at client side itself with regular expression. because server validation creates lots of overhead just for a simple validation.

Comment: of course you are right. but i want to work with situation when user has scripts turned off in his browser. So i want double checking here

Comment: `[HttpPost]
    public string SendAgreementEmail(string jsonOfLog)
    {
       //perform validation
        return Convert.ToString(jsonOfLog);
    }`  , try like this, perform your validation inside the fucntion adn return appropriate message or error code

Comment: Is `ModelState.IsValid` coming true, even when email is null? Have you debugged it with breakpoint? I am not able to replicate this scenario on my side. I have exactly you code.

Comment: thank you. i wanted to do in this way unless mvc has no way to do automatically in my case

Comment: @Alexander MVC supports automatic server validation. There is something going on in your code. In my code it is working absolutely fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used the same code as of yours, and server side validation is working absolutely fine for me. For simplicity sake I removed all properties, except the email property (as it is causing the main problem).

Model -

```
public class AgreementReportModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [RegularExpression(@"[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}", ErrorMessage = "Incorrect email")]
    public string EmailTo { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action -

```
public class AgreementController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public EmptyResult SendAgreementEmail(AgreementReportModel model)
    {
        bool t = ModelState.IsValid;
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

Index View -

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function SendEmailWithJquery() {

        var sendData = {
            EmailTo: ''
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Agreement/SendAgreementEmail",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(sendData),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }
        });
    };
</script>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="SendEmailWithJquery()" />
```

When I initiated **EmailTo : 'rami@gmail.com**, I get **ModelState.IsValid to true**.

[image]

When I initiated **EmailTo : null** or **EmailTo : ''**, I get **ModelState.IsValid to false**.

[image]

What to do next:

- Check your other data types, they might be culprits.
- Check you JavaScript input retrieval, document.getElementById, that can be giving your nulls.
- Check other parts of code, which can cause the problem, probably code like action filters etc.